# Verilog: Interface Module Input With a Reg

Tags: verilog

In the following code:

```
wire a;
reg b;
assign a = b;
ModuleName foo(a, other wire inputs, ... , wire outputs);
```

Assume that they are part of a top level module.

I wanted to run an always@ block but make changes in the input of a module instantiated in this module.

```
 always@(*) b = c^d; //Some Logic
```

The thing is, they are wires and cannot be on the LHS in an always@ block. Can I make changes to `b`and expect to see them in `a` i.e. the input of the Module foo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Every time you change `b`, `a` will change too. That is what an `assign` statement does. Remember this is hardware. The statement

```
assign a = b;
```

means 'drive `wire` `a` with whatever value `reg` `b` has for all time'.